# One Entity Have A Reference To Two Similar Entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa

A pair of domain entity classes, B1 and B2, which one of them mirrors the other mostly and shares its counterpart's id. Due to the system requirement, they need to be mapped to two DB tables. Both B1 and B2 has a one-to-many bi-directional relationship with another entity C. On the "many" side of the relationship, the entity C knows a relationship with both B1 and B2. Because of the similarity between B1 and B2, including the entity ID, I am wondering whether I could create an abstract entity class and let the entity C have a reference to only one entity. After looking into JPA mapping inheritance, I feel there isn't a suitable solution. And an embedded class likely isn't a suitable one either. If I really want to go with one entity reference route in C, I might need to add an entity ID attribute which refers either B1 or B2 to the entity C, but not defines any relationship between B1 or B2 and C. Any better approaches?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to place a `@OneToOne` mapping between B1 & B2, you can easily give C and link to B1 or B2.  A `@OneToOne` seems most appropriate given the fact that B1 & B2 share the same identifier.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The main reason of the mirror relationship between B1 and B2 is that they should be in two different applications/services. We are currently building a monolith application while an ideal approach is a microservice system. I didn't consider the one-to-one relationship betweem B1 and B2 due to the consideration.

Comment: Is it possible to extract all of the mirrored properties into their own `@Entity` and then make a `@ManyToOne` reference on B1 & B2?  Just throwing out ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your thought. That approach could work well with other scenarios, but not for this one. They are core domain objects and we try to design them for less fragment as possible.

Comment: Is it possible to use a Joined Inheritance strategy and then use an auxiliary field for the shared id?